# How to use setcookie in Page views counter function

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have this function for Page views counter:

```
function PageViews($postID) {
$c_key = 'views_count';
$cookie_count = $_COOKIE['views_count_'.$postID];
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $c_key, true);
if(!$cookie_count){
    setcookie('views_count_'.$postID , 'view', time()+999999999);
    if($count == ''){
        $count = 1;
        update_post_meta($postID, $c_key, $count);
        return $count;
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $c_key, $count);
        return $count;
    }
}else{
    return $count;
}
}
```

when I go to view post I get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at....
```

and my cookie doesn't set, this function in `function.php` . how to set this cookie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the cookie after output has already been sent to the browser. This is not allowed.  You need to call this function before any output is generated.

Comment: @AdamMo. You would do that by calling this function before you render any output to the screen. You have not shown where you call you function, just the function definition and the error. It is clear from the error message you are calling this function after some output has been sent to screen.